# Nonnegative constraint not working in with Spark ALS java api

Tags: java, apache-spark

I wanna use spark ALS with java api, I set Nonnegative as true, but I still see negative elements in the result. The function `setNonnegative()` seems not work, how come?

Comment: Can you place some example? I've checked Spark code and this parameter is used to check if Spark will be using NNLSSolver or CholeskySolver

Comment: my input is like this1,1,5.0
1,2,1.0
1,3,5.0
1,4,1.0
2,1,5.0
2,2,1.0
2,3,5.0
2,4,1.0
3,1,1.0
3,2,5.0
3,3,1.0
3,4,5.0
4,1,1.0
4,2,5.0
4,3,1.0
4,4,5.0 but the output is 2,[-0.8551104068756104, 3.1410577297210693, -3.323399305343628]
4,[-0.8551104068756104, 3.1410577297210693, -3.323399305343628] 1,[3.0539469718933105, 0.42312300205230713, -3.5726089477539062]
3,[3.0539469718933105, 0.42312300205230713, -3.5726089477539062] negative numbers exist in the result, how come? THX 4 answering